# An error ocurred while starting the kernel; matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, spyder

i installed ananconda on my computer.
i have a problem on my spyder:
An error ocurred while starting the kernel
Matplotlib is building the font cache; this may take a moment.

my spyder have a problem :
An error ocurred while starting the kernel
Matplotlib is building the font cache; this may take a moment.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.